# No controlling tty (open /dev/tty: No such device or adrress)

Tags: unix, shell, posix

При старте системы (QNX 6.5.0, образ собирал сам) появляется данная ошибка:

```
sh: No controlling tty (open /dev/tty: No such device or adrress)
sh: warning: won't have full job control
```

После этого неккоректно вводятся программы:

```
#ls
sh: dsl:cannot execute - No such file or directory
```

Как это исправить?

---

У меня в образе `.bsh` скрипт вызывает через sh скрипт `sysinit` с остальными системными службами, там в самом конце идет вызов:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin exec `which tinit` $P LOGNAME=root
```

, если вместо шелла запускать сразу tinit, то как быть с остальными службами которые ранее должны запускаться?

Comment: http://www.openqnx.com/phpbbforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=15864

Comment: Гуглить умею, что такое tinit знаю и где он вызывается тоже, решения проблемы в приведенной ссылке нет.

Comment: т.е. tinit вместо шелла запускать не помогло?

Comment: ещё по ключевым словам: http://qnx.org.ru/forum/index.php?topic=8184.0 // подробности лучше приводить в вопросе, а не в комментарии, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: >скрипт вызывает через sh ... в каком процессе это все дальше выполняется? в sh, а потом ты уже в нем tinit запускаешь. tinit должен первым идти, имхо. иначе у тебя sh родительский процесс, а tinit - child, разве нет?

Comment: Да, получается что первым sh вызывается, потом через него init. Почему init должен быть первым?

Answer (score 2):

Помогло следующее:
в .bsh скрипте образа после вызова

`display_msg Start COM1 driver in edit mode for Tooling Console
 devc-ser8250 -e -t8 -b115200 -u1 3F8,4`

Добавил:

`waitfor /dev/ser1
reopen /dev/ser1`

После вызова:

```
reopen /dev/con1
```

Добавил:

`reopen /dev/ser1
[+session] ksh &`

Как результат - все грузится без ошибок теперь. Спасибо за ваши подсказки.
Особенно помогла ссылка - http://qnx.org.ru/forum/index.php?topic=8184.0